# Confusing summation of $i$ not $j$, but $j$ is not defined

Tags: summation, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I am trying to write out the following log-likelihood:
$$\mathcal L(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \sum_{i} \left[ k_{i}^{out} (\boldsymbol{A}^*) \ln x_i + k_i^{in} (\boldsymbol{A}^*) \ln y_i\right] - \sum_{i \neq j} \ln(1 + x_i y_i). \tag{1}$$

I read it as, in the first term, the sum over all $i$, which is logical. But then, in the second sum, it says, a sum over all $i$ but not $j$. Which in principle is fine, but how does one determine $j$ in that instance? It's also not that the second sum, should be included in the first sum, because both sums have a subscript $i$  Is this a mistake in the publication, or is this still solvable?

In case the second sum should be a double sum, is the equation below, also a double sum? (this is from the exact same paper, but I don't think a double sum would be logical here)

\begin{align}
 & \sum_{j \neq i} \dfrac{x_i^* y_j^*}{1 + x_I^* y_j^*} = k_i^{out}(\boldsymbol{A}^*); \qquad \forall i. \tag{2} \\
& \sum_{j \neq i} \dfrac{x_j^* y_i^*}{1 + x_j^* y_i^*} = k_i^{in}(\boldsymbol{A}^*); \qquad \forall i. \tag{3}
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thank you José. I was on stack overflow earlier and this wasn't possible! I will change it!

Answer (score 1):

The notation means sum over all pairs $(i,j)$ such that $i\neq j$. What exactly "all pairs" means should follow from the context.

Comment: I am sorry I included the wrong picture! I have edited the new version

Comment: now you see why it is so confusion right?

Comment: There is no confusion. The first sum is over $i$ and the second one is over all pairs as I described above.

Comment: So is this a short notation of a double sum?

Comment: Yes it is a double sum.

Comment: I have added another example of the same paper in the main Q, is this also a double sum?

Comment: Because, in this second example, it wouldn't be logical to use the same notation, but then mean something completely different? and why wouldn't he put, $i \neq j$ there instead of $j \neq i$

Comment: No, the other example is not a double sum because $i$ is defined outside and only $j$ changes in the sum. You just have to keep track of which indices have been defined outside the scope of the sum.

Comment: Thank you Michal